# get Records from Excel sheet to MySQL database using php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to get records from Excel sheet to Mysql  database using Codeigniter php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best place to start:
[Code Igniter Excel library](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Excel_Plugin/)

You'll need to include the library (either in config/autoload, or with $this->load->excel) and fire up the examples that are listed in the CI wiki at that link. It's pretty straight forward.